# Why is int promoted to double and not float for implicit conversion

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, implicit-conversion

I'm currently learning C++ thought C++ Primer. In chapter 4.11 on Type Conversion, I noticed that the chapter rarely talks about the implicit conversion from integral to floating point types, but really focused mostly on conversion within the integral types. Thus, I am not really sure about the rules of conversion from integral type to floating point type.

My question is from the chapter's example:

```
int ival = 3.541 + 3
```

The chapter mentioned that 3 is converted to a `double` type before the addition of 3.541.

The question stems from the fact that for most integral types, they are mostly promoted to `int` during implicit conversion unless they are unable to fit into `int`. Since `int` and `float` both the same size of 4 bytes, and that 3.0 and 3.541 can perfectly fit into a `float`, why is the higher order `double` used for implicit conversion in this case as opposed to `float`? Does this mean that for any integral type to floating point type implicit conversion, the integral type will be converted to a `double` regardless of the precision or size?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: 3.541 can't fit into a float at all, it's a repeating fraction in binary.

Comment: if you do that `int ival = 3.541f + 3` then float is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`3.541` is a double. So that's what the other argument needs to be converted to.

Suffixes are used to denote the precision of a literal, `3.541f` (or F) would be a float, `3.541L` (or l) would be a long double. The default (no suffix) is double. Source http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal .

3.541 does not fit into any of those lengths, as it's a repeating fraction in binary. The real value will be the floating point value as close to 3.541 as possible (like 3.540999999999999925393012745189480483531951904296875 in case of a double).

Answer (score 1):

By default if you write something like:

```
int ival = 3.541 + 3;
```

`3.541` will be considered a `double`, because without any suffix, that is what is assumed by the compiler by default. If you wanted it to be treated like a float, do this:

```
int ival = 3.541f + 3; //See the 'f' there. For floats
```

Also, if you are wondering why sometimes `3.1541` is not represented properly is probably because its binary representation isn't accurate enough. Read [this article for more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx)